# How can I get Silverlight to create a Certificate and store it in local storage?

Tags: silverlight, encryption, silverlight-4.0, certificate, local-storage

I'm trying to create a x509 certificate on the client side, and store it in local storage, but I'm having trouble doing it.

What is the right way to create a x509 Cert (self-signed, or otherwise) and save it into local storage?

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not provide any class to allow to create your own X.509 certificate. In general *most* people will p/invoke into CryptoAPI - but this is **not** an option for Silverlight (for most scenarios anyway).

The Mono project provides a [Mono.Security.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security) assembly that works under Windows (but might require a bit of work to build on Silverlight since that .NET profile is weak on the crypto side, e.g. lack of RSA).

In any case **Mono.Security.dll** includes a fully managed X-509 related classes (including RSAManaged) that allows you to create your own, self-signed, certificate. You can find some sample code by looking at Mono's **[makecert](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/makecert.cs)** tool.

Comment: Would SL4 (which can PInvoke (I think)) support this?

Comment: IIRC SL4 supports COM and it *could* be possible using CAPICOM (I have not checked that for **many** years). SL5 has support for p/invokes (but I never tried it) and it likely has limitations (like SL 4/3 has with doing interop) so it won't work for every kind of application. Maybe it can work in your app ?!? can't say :)